# validation accuracy is stuck at 99.44% from the first training epoch while training accuracy and loss are increasing and decreasing respectively

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, nlp

and I don't understand why is this happening is it a problem with the architecture or the training itself I tried slightly different models but with the same problem.

its for jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge

[image: model]
[image: training]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Accuracy is not very meaningful if the classes are imbalanced. Please add details: how many instances? Proportion by class? What kind of data, type of task?